# Take the difference in two SQL dumps for update/alter statements?

Tags: sql, database

Are there libraries that focus on taking two database exports, finding the differences and creating update/alter statements for it? Basically an update script from export A to export B.

For instance this:

```
-- Version 1
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- Version 2
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- Would result in this:
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
  ADD `description` text;
```

**Edit:** this question is related to *libraries* for MySQL, not tools.

Comment: There are 3rd-party tools that do this. RedGate would be a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few *MySQL* comparison tools out there.

- [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php)
- [Redgate MySQL Compare](http://mysql-compare.com/)

Comment: They come close to what I had in mind. Though what I'm really looking for are libraries, not so much tools.

Comment: More tools Here:
http://blog.devart.com/comparing-two-oracle-schemas-is-simple-now.html

Comment: Also, MySQL Workbench might be of interest

Answer (score 0):

RedGate http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index-b offer a very good and stable solution to this.

I believe ultimate edition of Visual Studio 2010 can also compare schemas however I'm not sure if it will generate the ALTER scripts for you.

**Edit:**
I just remembered this http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/ too however I didn't have much luck when I last looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

This node module could be useful. It diffs live databases, but then it should be simple to create a live database from an SQL dump.

https://github.com/contra/dbdiff